# what does example,= mnist_train.take(1)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I not understand what does the ,= operator in this case, can anyone explain me what is the meaning of that?

```py
mnist_dataset = tfds.load("mnist")
mnist_train = mnist_dataset["train"]

example,= mnist_train.take(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

When eager mode is enabled or in TF 2.0, `example ,= dataset.take(1)` returns a tuple (data, label), in this case it is a single training example. And `example = dataset.take(1)` will return `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter` object.

Answer (score 0):

`example,` unpacks the value from the RHS value (in this case, a dataset with one element) into the LHS tuple. Unpacking a dataset is equivalent to iterating over it: each value iterated over becomes an element of the resulting tuple. In this case, this works because the dataset has only one element (`dataset.take(1)`). If your dataset had three elements, the LHS tuple would need three elements, for example:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)  # {0, 1, 2}
a, b, c = dataset

# a: tf.Tensor: 0
# b: tf.Tensor: 1
# c: tf.Tensor: 2
```